# non-const lvalue reference to type '' cannot bind to a temporary of type ' *'

Tags: c++, class, reference, queue, constants

Demo code

In file A:

```
class Queuetest{
...
queue<myclass>* mMyQueue = new queue<myclass>;

void addMyclass(myclass& myclassobject){
    mMyQueue->push(myclassobject);
}
...
};
```

In file B:

```
...
Queuetest* mQueuetest = new Queuetest();

mQueuetest->addMyclass(new myclass(...));
...
```

So the compile tell me :

**reference to type 'myclass' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'myclass *'**

Some similar case give me the reason:

> The C++ standard does not allow the binding of an anonymous temporary to a reference, although some compilers allow it as an extension. (Binding to a const reference is allowed.)

But there is no way to show me how to solve it;

I want to use a queue to control my object, and make the object work like a FIFO; add the new one, and pop the last one, releasing the memory for that object automatically;

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: "addMyclass(myclass& myclassobject)" wants to get a reference while "mQueuetest->addMyclass(new myclass(...));" gives a pointer to the function. You should decide what you want! If you want to declare with reference and have temporaries, than you have to add a interface for rvalue ref to move the objects in.

Comment: The code as is doesn't need any pointers.  You should really get rid of them.

Comment: I bet you're a Java programmer, trying to put everything on the heap out of habit. Google composition and perfect forwarding if you want to do things the right way.

Comment: @NathanOliver So Is there a good way to come true my aim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least use the const qualifier

```
void addMyclass( const myclass& myclassobject){
    mMyQueue->push(myclassobject);
}
```

Or overload the function like

```
void addMyclass(myclass&& myclassobject){
    mMyQueue->push(myclassobject);
}
```

And instead of

```
mQueuetest->addMyclass(new myclass(...));
```

use

```
mQueuetest->addMyclass(myclass(...));
```

because the queue is declared as storing objects of the type `myclass` instead of pointers to objects.

```
queue<myclass>* mMyQueue = ...
      ^^^^^^^
```

Also it is unclear why you are using a pointer to `std::queue` as a data member.

```
queue<myclass>* mMyQueue = new queue<myclass>;
```

Just declare the data member like

```
queue<myclass> mMyQueue;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct myclass
{
};

class Queuetest
{
private:
    std::queue<myclass> mMyQueue;

public:
    void addMyclass( const myclass &myclassobject )
    {
        std::cout<< "void addMyclass( const myclass &myclassobject )\n";
        mMyQueue.push(myclassobject);
    }

    void addMyclass( myclass &&myclassobject )
    {
        std::cout<< "void addMyclass( myclass &&myclassobject )\n";
        mMyQueue.push(myclassobject);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Queuetest test;

    test.addMyclass( myclass() );

    myclass m;

    test.addMyclass( m );
}
```

Its output is

```
oid addMyclass( myclass &&myclassobject )
void addMyclass( const myclass &myclassobject )
```

Comment: add "const"  shows:  reference to type 'const myclass' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'myclass *'

Comment: @iknow34languages A const reference can be bind to rvalue.

Comment: remove "new" shows:non-const lvalue reference to type 'myclass' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'myclass'

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow If add "const" and remove "new" still failed;

Comment: @iknow34languages Close this question selecting the best answer and then ask a new question showing the modified code and the error message.

Comment: i think i have not solved the problem now ,after i tried the two ways;

Comment: @iknow34languages The problem is solved as it was declared. We do not know what errors you have at this time.

Comment: @iknow34languages See my updated post. Pay attention to the syntax of the statement mMyQueue.push(myclassobject);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198017/discussion-between-iknow34languages-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: You forgot to std::move in the rvalue overload. A captured rvalue is an lvalue inside the function. Alternatively write a template function with perfect forwarding.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i ll take your code to do a test ,and reply your later, thanks

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  i tried the  "  test.addMyclass( myclass() ); "  it can work;   And i make a mistake that i add "static "  before " std::queue<myclass> mMyQueue; "  and it compile failed;  Thanks very much !!

Comment: @iknow34languages Close your question selecting the best answer.

Comment: You still do a copy instead of move in the rvalue overload.

Answer (score 3):

You're handing it a pointer instead of an instance.